# Mysql delete from join result

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-delete

**Delete does not work:**

```
DELETE FROM categories c
RIGHT JOIN product_categories pg
ON c.id = pg.category_id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
GROUP BY pg.category_id
```

**When using select instead, it does work:**

```
SELECT pg.category_id as pg_id
FROM categories c
RIGHT JOIN product_categories pg
ON c.id = pg.category_id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
GROUP BY pg.category_id
```

I used the select to test it out and the select give the correct results with an array of pg_id's in this case.

What did I miss with the delete?

Comment: What influence do you expect `product_categories` to have on the delete?

Comment: @Brian No influence really. I want to delete all rows in c that is a result of the join. Any ideas?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is misleading at best, and simply erroneous at worst.

Comment: Are you getting SQL syntax error? I think your query can not execute

Comment: @EdwardN "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'c"

Comment: @Strawberry You guys talk in riddles today, but alright, GROUP BY is bad. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: ...says the guy who uses RIGHT JOIN !

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm an idiot, but I don't see any difference between the above `delete` query and the simpler `delete from categories c where c.id is null`.  That's why I asked my earlier question.

Comment: @Brian The nulls only emerge in the context of the join - so your suggestion is nonsensical. However, you're also correct in so far as the original proposition suffers from a similar absence of logic.

Comment: @Strawberry the light just went on.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the time to figure out what was wrong in my original code and also how to delete what I wanted.

This is inspired much from @Strawberry:

**Select**

```
SELECT DISTINCT pg.category_id pg_id, c.id c_id
FROM categories c
LEFT
JOIN product_categories pg
  ON c.id = pg.category_id
  WHERE pg.category_id IS NULL;
```

**Delete**

```
DELETE c
FROM categories c
LEFT
JOIN product_categories pg
  ON c.id = pg.category_id
  WHERE pg.category_id IS NULL;
```

The result from the select is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pg_id] =>
        [c_id] => 2
    )

)
```

If `pg_id` is empty, it will delete the row in where `c_id` is `2` in this case in `c`.

Comment: I think that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated query instead.

```
DELETE
FROM categories C
WHERE not exists (SELECT * 
                  FROM product_categories PC 
                  WHERE PC.category_ID = C.ID)
```

Basically delete all categories which haven't been used in a product_Category.

My rule of thumb is if I don't need data from a table, don't include it in the join/from; note this isn't a hard fast rule.  If you're using it as a filter then it belongs in the where or having clauses.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a valid, and conventional SELECT query might be as follows...

```
SELECT DISTINCT pg.category_id pg_id
           FROM product_categories pg 
           LEFT
           JOIN categories c
             ON c.id = pg.category_id
          WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

The corresponding DELETE query might look like this:

```
         DELETE pg
           FROM product_categories pg 
           LEFT
           JOIN categories c
             ON c.id = pg.category_id
          WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: He does not delete the product_categories table

Comment: @EdwardN I know, but at present, the alternative makes no sense. How do you delete NULL (i.e. non-existant) rows?

Comment: I got you. The query make no sense.

Comment: I agree that something is not correct here. I will look into this but this is probably the closest answer so far.

Comment: @Strawberry I finally got the time to get back to this and because of your answer I'm quite sure I got it correct now. I posted my own answer, but gave you a vote up as thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can not have GROUP BY in UPDATE, DELETE. In case, your query is really need a GROUP BY, you can place it in a subquery like this

```
DELETE c
FROM categories AS c
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT pg.category_id
   FROM categories c
   RIGHT JOIN product_categories pg
   ON c.id = pg.category_id
   WHERE c.id IS NULL
   GROUP BY pg.category_id) AS t ON c.category_id = t.category_id
```

**Updated:**

About your query, it not makes sense. You want to delete records that do not exits in the **category** table

Comment: GROUP BY serves no useful purpose in this query.

Comment: @Strawberry I just want to point out that GROUP BY does not allow in the DELETE. About a query, yes you are right